# grails many_to_many custom mapping table

Tags: grails, many-to-many

Is it possible to generate my custom mapping table in the many to many relationships in grails? I need to introduce an extra parameter in the mapping table and that is the need for creating my own custom mapping table :(

Answer (score 1):

Sure - you just need to map the join table with a domain class and change your many-to-many to two many-to-ones. See http://www.grails.org/Many-to-Many+Mapping+without+Hibernate+XML